# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application' when deploying Django app to AWS EB

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Django Python 3.8 project to Elastic Beanstalk on Amazon Linux 2/3.4.2 64bit.

I have the following code in `.ebeextensions/django.config`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: pos.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: pos.settings
```

I see this error all the time in the logs `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'`.

I've tried to write the config file this way, but still the same error:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: pos/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides having this block in django.config I also had to specify the wsgi path in elastic beanstalk cinfiguration.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "pos.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "pos.wsgi:application"
```

[image]